# Splitby functionality and combine to two columns in solr results

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr4

I am using Lucid Works to create index of solr.

Source : Database

I have two similar columns in my database, Party1, Party2.

I am using a SQL Statement like this;

```
SELECT top 1000000 OrderId as id
, Party1 as PartyNameFirst
, Party2 as PartyNameLast
FROM dbo.vw_SolrRPSTRD
```

I wanted to get both Party as a single fieled, seperated by ",". I know it is deals with multivalued field and splitby function.
But unable to get sample.

Please guide me in this.

Thanks In Advance....

Comment: How you are doing data import ?

Comment: I am importing data from SQL. Can anybody tell me what is the real use of SplitBy function??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using SQL Server. You can concatenate them in SQL itself and keep a single-valued Solr field:

```
SELECT top 1000000 OrderId as id, 
Party1 + ', ' + Party2 as PartyName
FROM dbo.vw_SolrRPSTRD
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the real use of SplitBy function??

Comment: Solr `splitBy` as mentioned at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer is used for splitting a string into multiple strings and storing in a Solr multi-valued field. See the example given in that link for field `mailId` - `<field column="mailId" splitBy="," sourceColName="emailids"/>`. `mailId` is a Solr multi-valued field. So if your DB has `emailids` field as `a@xyz.com,b@xyz.com` then in Solr these two values will be stored for `mailId` field.